# Find Number of Characters in a specific line in text file

Tags: c#

I have a text file which contains 3 lines each having more than 1000 characters. Each Line have a specific value in offsets 1 to 3. I am trying to find the number of characters (Space is also considered as a character) in a specific line which have a specific character. I have tried the below code which gives me the whole number of characters in the text file.

```
var lineCount = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\ValidFile.txt").Length;
Console.WriteLine(lineCount + "Line Count");
```

Comment: What is the problem? You want the line count for each line?

Comment: I am trying to find the number of characters (Space is also considered as a character) in a specific line which have a specific word or number in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the lines, you can simply do:

```
var file = new StreamReader(@"D:\ValidFile.txt");
string line = null;
int lineNumber = 0;
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Line " + (lineNumber++) + ": " + line.Length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me customize this code according to my requirement and check

Comment: @MidhunMathew Just corrected a typo.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ReadAllLines`:

```
var lineCount = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\ValidFile.txt")
                    //.Where (p => ...) // put your condition here
                    .Select((p,i) => new {Index = i, Count = p.Length})
                    .ToDictionary(p=>p.Index, p=>p.Count);
```

Where key is line number

Answer (score 0):

To read line by line

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("c:\\ValidFile.txt"))
{
    if(line.Contains("**SpecificWord**"){
    Console.WriteLine(line.length);
    }
}
```